# Is there any app which can create quiz based on freemind?

Tags: anki

I'm using [Freemind](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) for knowledge accumulation.  Separately I use [anki cards](https://ankiweb.net) for memorization.

What I'm missing is some tool to automatically create quizzes (best if it could be of anki type) for `freemind` is there any such tool?

Comment: FreeMind and Anki are both cross-platform. Could you please specify whether you need the software for a particular operating system?

Comment: in general I use `ubuntu` as desktop and `android` as mobile phone.  (if none for `ubuntu` and none for `android` then I can install `windows` for that purpose if something would exist on that OS).

Answer (score 2):

This post is old, but perhaps others will be interested. Not sure if this works or has experienced bitrot, but there is [freemind-to-anki](https://github.com/seichner/freemind-to-anki) If you search google with "Freemind (or Freeplane) to Anki", you'll find some other results too which may or may not be current. If you had been on OS X, another interesting option exists: [MarginNoteX][3], it also has an iOS app that syncs and it exports to Anki. I have no connection with MarginNoteX, but I do use it. I myself am looking into the Freeplane -> Anki route. Another interesting project, which I do use, is org-drill for use with Emacs and org-mode. It isn't related to your question, but I'll leave it here for others.